# calculate the sum of the intervals based on the binary array

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, numpy

I have two matrix:

1. Binary A = [[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]];
2. Matrix of values B = [[100, 200, 300, 400], [400, 300, 100, 200]];

I want to calculate the sum of the intervals that are formed by the rows of the matrix A. For my exmpl. result will be follow: R = [[300, 0, 700, 0], [0, 0, 300, 0]] (generally, it is not necessary to set zeros [[300, 700], [300]] - it's right solution too)

I already wrote the code, but very very terrible (although it works correctly)

```
def find_halfsum(row1, row2):
    i = 0
    result = []
    count = 0
    for j in range(len(row1)):
        if row1[j] == 1 and count == 0:
            i = j
            count += 1
        elif row1[j] == 1:
            count += 1
        if count == 2:
            if j == i + 1:
                result.append(row2[i])
            else:
                result.append(sum(row2[i:j]))
            i = j
            count = 1
        if j == len(row1) - 1:
            result.append(sum(row2[i:j + 1]))
    return result
```

Someone knows beautiful solutions (which will be faster)(preferably with the help of a numpy)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with python, but I don't think you need that many lines

```
define halfSum(matrixA, matrixB):
    sum = 0;
    for i in range(len(matrixA)):
        if matrixA[i] == 1:
           sum += matrixB[i]
        return sum;
```

Comment: I did not understand what is written here, such code will exit the loop on the first iteration. Also, you just increase the sum only where there is a unit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.add.reduceat`:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]])
>>> B = np.array([[100, 200, 300, 400], [400, 300, 100, 200]])
>>> 
>>> [np.add.reduceat(b, np.flatnonzero(a)) for a, b in zip(A, B)]
[array([300, 700]), array([300])]
```

Comment: Oh, very interesting, thank you very much. I think that's what I need.